# Print prime numbers using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, loops, primes, pointer-arithmetic, function-definition

My function *writePrime* has to write all prime numbers from array using pointer arithmetic. I cannot use any other function except *main* and *writePrime*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void writePrime(int arr[], int n) {
  int *q = arr, *qq = arr, i, prime;
  while (q < arr + n) {
    while (qq < arr + n) {
      i = 1;
      if (*qq % i != 0)
        continue;
      else
        prime = 1;
      i++;
      qq++;
    }
    if (prime == 1)
      printf("%d ", *q);
    q++;
  }
}
int main() {
  int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96};
  int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
  writePrime(arr, n);
  return 0;
}
```

This code just prints the same unchanged array. How could I modify this to work?

Comment: Think about when `*qq % i != 0` will happen when `i` is 1. (But you have other issues, too.)

Comment: `*qq % i`, with `i=1`, will always be 0. So you'll consider every number to be prime. Starting from 2 will be the first step to get your function working.

Comment: You never set `prime` to zero; you should define and initialize it inside the first loop before the second loop.  It also seems to mean 'non-prime' — you seem to think it will be zero initially and set it to `1` when `*qq` is composite.  You should probably break the inner loop when you set `prime = 1;` (so you'd need braces after the `else`.  Your printing condition is inverted — at least, you'll print every composite number as it stands.  And testing for divisibility by `1` is unexciting.  Etc.  Your code can be fixed but the algorithm is horribly inefficient for larger numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `n` should be declared as having the type `size_t`

```
size_t n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
```

because it is the type of an expression with the `sizeof` operator.

So the function should be declared like

```
void writePrime( const int arr[], size_t n );
```

Using two loops with two pointers within the function does not make a sense.

Each variable is divisible by 1. So this code snippet

```
  i = 1;
  if (*qq % i != 0)
    continue;
  else
    prime = 1;
```

also does not make any sense.

And you are using initially uninitialized variable prime that must be reset before processing each element of the array.

The function can be defined the following way

```
void writePrime( const int arr[], size_t n )
{
    for ( const int *p = arr; p != arr + n; ++p )
    {
        int prime = *p % 2 == 0 ? *p == 2 : *p != 1;

        for ( int i = 3; prime && i <= *p / i; i += 2 )
        {
            if ( *p % i == 0 ) prime = 0;
        }

        if ( prime ) printf( "%d ", *p );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `*p != 1` --> `*p >1` to correctly handle negative values.